# For an activity called in a loop, does the retry policy for the activity apply to each run?

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

For a given workflow with activity A with max retries set to 3, if I have the following piece of code:

```
for (String type: types) {
    activityA.process(type);
}
```

and types in this case is ["type1", "type2", "type3"]
So if activityA processed type1 successfully and starts processing type2 and fails for some reason,

1. Will the retry policy for activityA apply each time a type is run or will it be 3 retries across all activity types?
2. If the workflow fails when executing type2, will the workflow restart from the beginning and process type1 again or will it start from type2?

Answer (score 1):

For 1. The retry policy will be working independently for each activity. So each type will have three retries.

For 2. Workflow failure is a terminal state for workflow execution. It would not retry automatically unless you specify a retry policy when starting the workflow. When workflow retry. It will start from very beginning.

See also https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/concepts/workflows/#workflow-retries

Or maybe what you asked is if worker fails instead of workflow? Cadence is very fault tolerant to worker failure, workflow will automatically resume running from what it has left before the previous worker dies.

See also https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/concepts/workflows/#state-recovery-and-determinism